# Twitter icon does not show up in share link

Tags: html, twitter

I am looking at these docs:

https://dev.twitter.com/web/tweet-button

I tried a couple of their examples, like so:

```
<a class="twitter-share-button" href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet">
  Tweet
</a>
```

However, this only displays the text "Tweet" without an image. I assume an image is supposed to be included, so what am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the javascript file.

```html
<script type="text/javascript" async src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"></script>
<a class="twitter-share-button" href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet">
  Tweet
</a>
```

Comment: nice...weirdly when I include this script in an Angular5 template, it never gets loaded, whether I use the async attribute or not...I looked at the Network tab, and it's nowhere to be seen

Comment: here is the answer: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/4903, weird.

Comment: Stuff happens :D